# How to append integer prefix to a file name in c?

Tags: c, linux, file, file-handling

> I need to write a program to create a file using system calls.

The input file name is given as a macro (#define filename "/log/data.log"`).
I have to add a number to the file name and change it as "/log/data_1.log or /log/data_2.log" based on the requirement.

I am using `open()` to create the file.

```
#define filename "/log/data.log"
int fd=0;
int num; //This is the number I want to add to the file name

if(fd = open(file_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666) ) < 0 )
 {  
   printf("Could not open the log file: %s\n", strerror(errno) );
  return -1;
 }
```

Comment: take a look at `sprintf()`

Comment: I tried with sprintf but It is giving segmentation error

Comment: @HimajaKrishna if you get a segmentation error you have done somthing wrong. But without seeing your code we can't help much

Comment: FYI, something you append is a suffix, not a prefix.

Comment: How do you decide where to inject the integer?  What if the filename does not contain a `.`?  What if it contains multiple occurrences of `.`?  Are you always inserting `_x` (where x is the integer) after the string "data", or always before the string ".log", or before the first `.`, or before the last `.`, or somewhere else?  Be specific; computers like specificity.  Once you define the problem accurately, often the solution becomes very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
#define filenametemplate "/log/data_%d.log"
...
int num; //This is the number I want to add to the file name    
...
char filename[100];
sprintf(filename, filenametemplate, num);
// now filename contains "/log/data123.log" (if num contains 123)
...
```

Comment: Or [snprintf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) (filename, 100, filenametemplate, num);

Comment: Or even better `snprintf (filename, sizeof(filename), filenametemplate, num);`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [asprintf()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) GNU extension: it is available on Linux, Mac OS, FreeBSD and others.

Essentially, you initialize a char pointer to NULL, then pass it to asprintf when you want to create a new string.  It will dynamically allocate memory for it, and return the length of the resulting string.  It will return a negative value if an error occurs.  You'll need the following at the beginning of your C program to expose these features,

```c
#define  _GNU_SOURCE   /* Needed on Linux for asprintf() to be exposed */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* For free(), exit() and EXIT_FAILURE */
#include <stdio.h>     /* For asprintf() and stderr */
#include <string.h>    /* For strerror() */
#include <errno.h>     /* For errno */
```

and then, in your main() or elsewhere,

```c
    char *filename = NULL;
    if (asprintf(&filename, "/log/data_%d.log", num) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot construct log file name: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot create log file: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        free(filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Filename is no longer needed; free it */
    free(filename);
    filename = NULL;
```

Comment: `asprintf` is overkill and non standard.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Unlike snprintf(), asprintf() does not suffer from arbitrary length limitations and assumptions.  Which, in my opinion, makes it superior.  It is also available on all systems I care about, including the one tagged in the question.